# is "either...or" a term acceptable in claim

Tags: claims, claim-construction, dependent-claim

suppose I need to write a claim for below image, that panel B can **either** attached to the surface of panel A **or** to the edge of panel A, is this acceptable in claim, or I have to use alternative in this situation.

how to word it technically? I was told that only writing the relative position and construction, not mention the function if possible, like welding, screwed, or glued etc...thanks

[image]

Comment: Does this picture show one of two possible positions ? Or is the relative position the same in both cases and the point of attachment different?

Comment: the picture just show one possible position, you might see the attaching edge is almost in the center of panel A surface,  if the panel B edge can attach to the edge of panel A? then could I use "either ...or "" I don't want to limit the attachment as picture only.

Answer (score -1):

Can you not simply state "panel B is attached to panel A"? That way the location of the attachment is not defined.

As a side note, I don't think "surface of panel A", unless intentionally limited, would exclude any "edges".

Comment: Where it is attached can make a functional difference and could constitute a completely distinct embodiment.

Comment: thanks guy, I think this is a good idea, what I am concern is whether the examiner will think the claim is unclear or could not specify the relationship of the panels? is it possible? I study some patent and find that they did use :-" either...or"